# How to move an SSIS package from one server moved to another

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I was wondering how I would be able to get an SSIS package from a SQL Server that has already been deployed and move it to another SQL Server?

NOTE: I do not have the original package project to just install it on the other server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on how the package has been deployed.  If it's in MSDB, you can right-click the package in SSMS and choose Export Package.  You can save it locally as file and the deploy that to another server.  If it's on the file system, you can just copy the .dtsx file.

Bear in mind that any hard coded connections may not be able to be changed, unless you can load the package in BIDS.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

- Connect to the new server SSIS through SSMS.
- Open Stored Packages and right click MSDB.
- Select "Import Package...", set the Server to the source instance (MSDB where the package resides).
- Click button for "Package path:" and select the package from the list.
- Set the "Protection level" if applicable or leave the default.
- Click OK.

You will now have the package transferred to the second server and saved in MSDB. It is not certain that the SSIS package will work without modifications as mentioned by previous post.